# Codeigniter: Best approach to passing values between multiple views

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm a bit of a newbie to Codeigniter. :)

I have a web site member registration flow with several pages and wanted to find out what's the best way to 'store' data between views until the registration flow is complete and I can create a member record?

Should I create a temp table and save the info there based on session id?
Or should I try to pass a data array to each view and then store the info in hidden fields (then I can get the values again from the controller via POST)?
Or perhaps I could have a 'global variable' in my controller that stores all the data until I'm all done with the registration flow and can save the information then into the database.

Any best practices approaches?

Comment: why not in one page with multistep form?

Comment: The best approach to passing values between multiple views is not to pass values between views and use controllers for this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a few options but here are the two I would pick:

You could create a form that works as a tab system that runs off JavaScript. That way you only really have one form on the page in terms of the HTML but you hide and show one page at a time with JavaScript. This essentially fixes all of your problems.

If that doesn't work for you then I suggest $_SESSIONS as well. BUT, not the native codeigniter sessions. This is the only thing I don't like about Codeigniter is that it uses Cookies instead of PHP native $_SESSIONS. I use the following library to implement PHP $_SESSIONS specifically for codeigniter https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Native-session

While most people do have cookies turned on, your still alienating some potential customers. This can easily be fixed by just using native PHP $_SESSIONS

Hope it works out - Good luck!